# Using proxy when sending email. C#

Tags: c#, email, proxy

I have a program which is sending emails to my clients. The thing i wanna do is to hide the ip from which  the email was send. Is this even possible if yes how? This is my code:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(email, target, title, msg);

            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(email, password);

            try
            {
                smtpClient.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed; Console.WriteLine($"Error occured while trying to send email:\n{e.Message}"); Console.ResetColor(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the wrong side. Gmail already strips the IP address of the client. If you own an email server this can be configured as well.

Comment: In my case when i press "Show original" in the sent email i can find the ip of my pc. :| 
Received: from DESKTOP-MYPCNAME ([my_ip])